# MVC - Model not working correctly

Tags: php, codeigniter

This is the code for my controller:

```
class products extends CI_Controller {
public function index() {
    $this->load->model('getproducts');
    $this->load->view('productlist');
}
}

?>
```

When I load this, it returns a blank page, however when I comment out the line that loads the model, it returns the view as expected (pointing to an error in the model).  Here is the code for the model:

```
<?php

class getproducts extends Model {
function listProducts() {

    $query = $this->db->get('ProjectProducts');

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        foreach ($query->result() as $row {
                $productdata[] = $row;
            }

    return $productdata;

    }
}
}

?>
```

Am I missing something obvious here?  I'm not even using any of the data from the model yet.

Comment: `class getproducts extends Model` wrong.should be `class getproducts extends CI_Model`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version you use of codeigniter

please note that you should extends CI_Model not model

```
class getproducts extends CI_Model {
```

Comment: Thanks developer, I had tried CI_Model previously whilst trying various other things - guess I fixed whatever problem I had before and then didn't try CI_Model again!

Answer (score 0):

> Please make sure your controller start letter be capital ie. upper
>   case and extend it as `CI_Model`

Comment: Class name with uppercase good practice.(cotroller model).But it works with lowercase too

Comment: you still have problem with extent from CI_Model?

Comment: Thanks Tariq, I had tried CI_Model previously whilst trying various other things - guess I fixed whatever problem I had before and then didn't try CI_Model again!

Answer (score 0):

you are missing

```
    function __construct() 
      {
            parent::__construct();   

      }
```

and this code before your function listProducts and after class starting hopefully this will resolve your issue.
and also use same function in your controller as well

Comment: nope its not missing. It will work without construct function.